# Best way to write consumers for many queues

Tags: python, redis, queue

Here's my situation:

I have a simple wrapper for Redis. What it does is, it takes an item (a dict) as input and puts it in a linked-list data type by doing an RPUSH. A request for a new item to be put at one queue may actually produce many new queues.

Now I want to read the left-most item in each queue without doing an LPOP. I need the items to stay in the queue. So what I do is, I do an LRANGE and get the left-most item from the queue.

My issue is I don't know how to write a consumer for my queues. I assume I should have one consumer for each queue? That means I will have many many instances of my consumer which sounds like a bad design decision.

Should I just get all the keys for all my queues and loop through them processing the left-most item repeatedly?

how should I write my consumer for the queues I have?
I'm honestly stuck and seems like none of the standard producer/consumer implementations answer my question. I have also looked into redis streams but I can't use those since the decision is out of my hands.

Comment: why do you want to do all this when https://github.com/rq/rq can do this?

Comment: @sonus21 Because the management has decided that we should write our own solution.

Comment: I might actually just loop through all the keys with at least one item.

Comment: got it, no that's not the correct way to handle it, there're many moving things. Give it a read https://medium.com/@sonus21/introducing-rqueue-redis-queue-d344f5c36e1b

or take some idea from rq

Comment: @sonus21 thank you very much. I know it's an aweful way to handle queues. That's why I've avoiding it. I actually did take a look at RQ's source code as well. I'm gonna read this article.